# Socket.io chat application working only on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, socket.io, chat

I'm completely new to web sockets and javascript.
I'm trying to create a chat application using javascript and socket.io.
It works on localhost (using "npm start" command line).

My question is: how can I access it from any other PC and use it like a real chat application?

I have the following error when I don't access it on localhost:

[image: error]

How can I host it for free and access it from anywhere? Can someone provide me an example of a socket.io chat application and step-by-step instructions?

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because if you are accessing to your website not from localhost, your hostname will not be the server address. So, in your `var socket = io();` you can specify the url that the user is accessing your website from.

Like this:

```
// get the url
let url = window.location.href.split("/");
url = url[0] + "//" + url[2];

const socket = io(url);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, it didn't work :(